# How much disk space I should give to Fast search Server

Tags: fast-search

I have content sources containing over 562,000 items. and I have given D drive  100 GB on the Fast Search Server.

I just got a warning of "Average (4 samples) disk free on D:\ is now 11%, which is below the warning threshold (15%) out of total size 100.0 GB"

I checked the space and found out  D:\data_fixml has used 33.6 GB; D:\data_index has used 33.9 GB.

My questions are:

1. If 100 GB space is big enough for over 500,000 items?
2. if not, what recommendation size I should give to the D drive?
3. If yes, how can I optimize the data inside data_fixml and data_index?

Thanks.

Comment: You can also delete the fixml files. In case you you won't be refeeding items they serve no purpose, and just keeps adding up....unfortuntaly. If you're not that bold, move it to a different disk if you can using mklink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the hardware recommendations for FAST Search Server [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff381239(v=office.14).aspx). Also other articles mention that virtual servers are faster, make sure you are using a virtual server.

1. I wouldn't think so.
2. This article is recommending 1TB on a RAID, across 6 spindles or more. That's what FAST Search is supposed to do, turn hardware value into speed for your searching needs. [Here is another article](http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2011/03/22/review-hardware-and-software-requirements-fast-search-server-2010-for-sharepoint/) that goes over a checklist on things to do to setup FAST Search server correctly and improve performance: